# req.body always return as undefined

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

i try to create register api but got some problem with req.body thats always return as undefined when i console.log it
here my controller.js

```js
const{ users: User} = require('../models/index');
const config = require('../config/config');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const jwtSignUser = (user) => {
const ONE_WEEK = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
return jwt.sign(user, config.authentication.jwtSecret, {
    expiresIn: ONE_WEEK
})
}
module.exports = {
    async register (req, res) {
        try{
            const user = await User.create(req.body)
            const userJson = user.toJSON()
            res.send({
                user: userJson,
                token : jwtSignUser(userJson)
            })
        } 
        
    catch (err){
        res.status(400).send({
            error:err
            
        })

    }
},
}
```

here my body parser declaration

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

anyone can notice whats wrong with it?

Comment: Please share what you are posting to your api along with the headers

Comment: i edited my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure, you must add route code after adding `body-parser` code

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Add your route after these lines
```